# Using u-substitution to solve for a general definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

If
$$\int_{0}^{9} f(x) dx = 4  $$

Find $$\int_{0}^{3} xf(x^2) dx  $$

I'm not sure if I'm approaching the problem correctly, but I would first start off with doing a u-sub

Choose $u = x^2$

Then, $du/2x = dx$

$$\int_{0}^{3} f(u)du/2 $$

$$(1/2)\int_{0}^{3} f(u)du$$

Change the limits since $u = x^2$

$$(1/2)\int_{0}^{9} f(u)du $$

Since we know that $$\int_{0}^{9} f(x) dx = 4  $$

$(1/2)(4)$

$2$

Comment: You've got it; nothing left to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final answer is **good**, but
$$\int\limits_{0}^{3} xf(x^2) \mathrm{d}x \neq\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{3} f(u) \mathrm{d}u$$
You should change the limits of the definite integral at the same time you change the variables:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{3} xf(x^2) \mathrm{d}x =\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{9} f(u) \mathrm{d}u$$
Because the 
$$\int\limits_{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$
means that you are integrating $f(x)$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$.

Or at least do something like this:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{3} xf(x^2) \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{x=0}^{x=3} f(u) \mathrm{d}u$$

Answer (score 1):

Looks like we had similar first instincts.

I tried using the substitution $u = \sqrt{x}$ on the first integral

with $du = \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}$

substituting for $u$ we get

$dx = 2udu$

When we rewrite the integral in terms of $u$ the limits go from 0 and 9 to 0 and 3 (Because $u = \sqrt{x}$).

And $f(x)$ is equivalent to $f(u^2)$

Thus,
$$
4 = \int_{0}^{9} f(x) dx = 2\int_{0}^{3} uf(u^2)du
$$

So we can see that the first integral is equal to double the value of the second integral.

$ 4 / 2 = 2 $

I think we saw this question in the same place, maybe I'll see you sometime this fall. Go Maroons!